# Python matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

My labels on this bar graph are off by one and I can't for the life of me figure out how to correct it. I have tried adding another series to the index but that then creats an error. Would this have something to do with the width of the bars? I'm lost.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


labels = ['cluster1','cluster2','cluster3','cluster4','cluster5','cluster6','cluster7']
Mean = df_mean['net_sale']
Count = df_p_count
Sum = df_p_sum

x = np.arange(len(labels))  # the label locations
width = 0.35  # the width of the bars

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects1 = ax.bar(x - width/2, Count, width, label='% of Sales')
rects2 = ax.bar(x + width/2, Sum, width, label='% of Revenue')

# Add some text for labels, title and custom x-axis tick labels, etc.
ax.set_ylabel('Percent')
ax.set_title('Discount Promotion Analysis')
ax.set_xticks(x, labels)
#ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
ax.set_xticklabels(['cluster1','cluster2','cluster3','cluster4','cluster5','cluster6','cluster7'])
ax.legend()



fig.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

[Graph Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEyjK.png)

Comment: The plot shown clearly doesn't correspond to the code. (Two bars of `0.35` wide would leave a gap of `0.30`).  Depending on what's inside the undefined variables `df_p_count` and `df_p_sum`, your labels would normally be placed correctly.  Note that pandas or seaborn could be handy to automatically place the bars nicely next to each other.  You might want to add some reproducible test data to better illustrate what you're doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your code doesn't produce the correct visualization is that `ax.set_xticks(x, labels)` is wrong, as `set_xticks` requires an array of number of the same length of `labels`.

```py
labels = ['cluster1','cluster2','cluster3','cluster4','cluster5','cluster6','cluster7']
# Mean = df_mean['net_sale']
# Count = df_p_count
# Sum = df_p_sum

Count = [0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0, 1.1]
Sum = [0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0, 1.1]

x = np.arange(len(labels))  # the label locations
width = 0.35  # the width of the bars

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects1 = ax.bar(x - width/2, Count, width, label='% of Sales')
rects2 = ax.bar(x + width/2, Sum, width, label='% of Revenue')

# Add some text for labels, title and custom x-axis tick labels, etc.
ax.set_ylabel('Percent')
ax.set_title('Discount Promotion Analysis')
ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
ax.legend()



fig.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: It seems you forgot to add some explaining text, nor did you provide hints about what OP might be doing wrong (apart from posting a non-reproducible question with a plot that doesn't correspond to the given code fragment.)

Comment: @AlexBodin Yes, this works. But your original code should also work, except if you're doing strange things with the data.

Comment: Johan, I don't understand your question. My code block is almost identical to the one posted by OP.  The only difference is that I generated random number because the dataframe was not provided. Hence, the code is very reproducible, with a plot that corresponds to the best of my ability to what OP is asking.

Comment: Well, your code is reproducible, but OP's is not.  Adding missing data isn't really answering the question.  You write *"`set_xticks` requires an array of number of the same length of labels."*, but the initial post seems to do just that.  Also note that there already are many similar answers on StackOverflow.